# Convert String variable to a List [Groovy]

Tags: java, string, list, groovy

How can I convert this `String` variable to a `List` ?

```
def ids = "[10, 1, 9]"
```

I tried with: as `List` and `toList();`

Comment: It is already a list in groovy?

Comment: This is a `List` do you want to convert it to a `String`?

Comment: But when I do 

ids.each{println it}

I have this result :
[</br>
1</br>
0</br>
,</br>
</br>
1</br>
]</br>

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
def l = Eval.me(ids)
```

Takes the string of groovy code (in this case "[10,1,9]") and evaluates it as groovy. This will give you a list of 3 ints.

Comment: http://www.jameswiseman.com/blog/2011/01/18/jslint-messages-eval-is-evil/

Comment: @AlexanderSuraphel Wrong language.

Comment: @chrylis Meaning?

Comment: @AlexanderSuraphel 
I will answer for him: your article is related to JavaScript (JSLint specifically). But question itself was about Groovy.

Comment: @MichaelA. Have you read the linked articles? The problem is not specific to JavaScript's Eval. It's the idea of passing a string to a method that is willing to execute anything. I felt that OP needs to know the risks as well.

Comment: I think a better link is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea. The ideas discussed apply to any language, not just JavaScript.

Comment: I would not consider using Eval as a safe option though.

Answer (score 31):

```
def l = ids.split(',').collect{it as int}
```

Comment: I think you want to make a string "10,1,9" into a list [10,1,9]

Comment: def id = ids.substring(1,ids.length()-1)
def l= id.split(',').collect{it as int}

Comment: I find this solution but I don't think is the best :

def id = ids.substring(1,ids.length()-1) def l= id.split(',').collect{it as int}

Comment: this works great for me, specifically in Jenkins, and using String instead of Int: `files = "'f1','f2'"

list = files.split(',').collect{it as String}

> list==['f1', 'f2']

> list[1]=='f2'
`

Comment: updating mine after the edit window closed: `list = versionFile.split(',').collect()` works fine for strings.

Answer (score 30):

**Use the built-in [JsonSlurper](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html)!**

[Using `Eval` could be **risky** as it executes any code](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) and the string manipulation solution will fail once the data type is changed so it is not adaptable. So it's best to use [JsonSlurper](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html).

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

//List of ints 
def ids = "[10, 1, 9]"
def idList = new JsonSlurper().parseText(ids)

assert 10 == idList[0]

//List of strings 
def ids = '["10", "1", "9"]'
idList = new JsonSlurper().parseText(ids)

assert '10' == idList[0]
```

Comment: This should definitely be accepted as right answer.

Comment: For me with strings this only works when I have : '["string1", "string2"]' and not with "['string1', 'string2']" running the code from jenkins.

Comment: @herm tested it myself and you're right. i've updated the answer

Answer (score 15):

This does work for me. And `Eval.me` will not work in Jenkins groovy script. I have tried.

```
assert "[a,b,c]".tokenize(',[]') == [a,b,c]
```

Comment: `Eval.me` didn't work for me as well (Jenkins groovy script). However, your solution gave a wrong result. My str is "['/a/b/c/d@2/e/f/g/h/i/j/k/l.py::m[n-10-3-9-0/8-17-12]',]" (actually I have more entries in the string, but this is the general idea). The tokenize returns only the inner list, i.e. "[n-10-3-9-0/8-17-12]'"

Comment: The higher scoring answers didn't work for me. This one did.

Comment: Could you explain what exactly tokenize(',[]') doing here?

Comment: Without the brackets, you get [[a, b, c]] as a result. Not sure I understand how adding the brackets removes the additional outer list.